Perturbation theory. Get xAct tensor component. Substitution for xAct tensors
I work with perturbations in FLRW metric with arbitary curvature. I'm following Weinberg's book.
In modified gravitation theory there is additional tensor S and I need to find it's perturbation in the following view:

dS_{0 0} = ...
dS_{0 i}=...
dS_{i j}=...

to past it in equations.
I have the Cristoffel subrules for this. I need

Setup indices of expression for perturbed S equal to {0,0}, {0,i}, {i, j}
Expand sum to time and purely space components
Replace all perturbed h with mixed components by h with only covariant components
Apply subrules for Cristoffel symbols

I have the following code:
<< xAct`xPert`
<< xAct`xCoba`
<< xAct`xTras`
<< xAct`Tensor`
DefManifold[M, 
  4, {\[Mu], \[Nu], \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Rho], \[Sigma], \[Kappa], \
\[Xi]}];
DefMetric[-1, g[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]], cd, {";", "\[Del]"}, PrintAs -> "g"];
DefMetricPerturbation[g, h, \[Epsilon]];
DefTensor[\[Phi][], M];
DefTensorPerturbation[\[Delta]\[Phi][LI[order]], \[Phi][], M]


S[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]] = 
 cd[\[Alpha]][\[Phi][]] cd[\[Beta]][\[Phi][]] Riemanncd[-\[Mu], -\
\[Alpha], -\[Nu], -\[Beta]] + 
  cd[-\[Mu]][cd[\[Alpha]][\[Phi][]]] cd[-\[Nu]][
    cd[-\[Alpha]][\[Phi][]]] - 
  cd[-\[Mu]][cd[-\[Nu]][\[Phi][]]] cd[-\[Alpha]][
    cd[\[Alpha]][\[Phi][]]] - 
  1/2 cd[-\[Alpha]][\[Phi][]] cd[\[Alpha]][\[Phi][]] \
Einsteincd[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]] + 
  g[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]]*(-(1/2) cd[\[Alpha]][
       cd[\[Beta]][\[Phi][]]] cd[-\[Alpha]][cd[-\[Beta]][\[Phi][]]] + 
     1/2 (cd[-\[Alpha]][cd[\[Alpha]][\[Phi][]]])^2 - 
     cd[-\[Alpha]][\[Phi][]] cd[-\[Beta]][\[Phi][]] Riccicd[\[Alpha], \
\[Beta]])

\[Delta]\[CapitalTheta][-\[Mu], -\[Nu]] = \[CapitalTheta][-\[Mu], -\
\[Nu]] // Perturbation // ExpandPerturbation // ContractMetric // 
   ToCanonical // Simplification

Thank you in advance.
